# Custom Control Inherited event not firing Up

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have a user control which inherits from `Control` and is drawn by myself using Graphics Object.

```
public class Line : Control
{
    public Point start { get; set; }
    public Point end { get; set; }
    public Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
}
```

This is main Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Line line = new Line() { start = new Point(50, 50), end = new Point(100, 100) };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Controls.Add(line);
        line.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(line_MouseEnter);
    }

    void line_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.DrawLine(line.pen, line.start, line.end);
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever the mouse rolls over the control the message box should pop up, but it doesn't. I have tried debugging and it seems that the event is never getting invoked. What's wrong here

Comment: Whether the line was visible on Form1?

Comment: You probably don't want the Paint event of the Form, try overriding the OnPaint method in your Line control, and use `e.Graphics` instead of `CreateGraphics`.  As far as the MouseEnter event, it's not clear "where" your control is.  Try setting the Location and Size properties of your control.

Comment: @LarsTech Yup that was the mistake i was making and spent 15 mins scratching my head before finally able to figuring it out. Thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your Control is visible but has **Size of Empty**. The line you see is not the line drawn on your Control, it's drawn on your form and that's why you thought your line is visible. You want to create your line which has an arbitrary direction. I think that's a little hard to do, you have to calculate the `Rectangle` of your line (one of the sides is your line thickness) depending on the angle made by your line direction and the horizontal line. If you can calculate that `Rectangle`, you have to use the `Region` property to make your line control exactly fit its `Rectangle`. Something like `yourLine.Region = new Region(calculatedRectangle);`. For that complexity , many UI library just supports `Horizontal line` and `Vertical line` because we can calculate their `Rectangle` easily and they are used more frequently than other kind of lines. Here is the code for a Horizontal line, I don't have time to dig into coding a full-feature line as you want, but you may want to try yourself:

```
public class Line : Control
{    
  Color lineColor = Color.Red;
  public Color LineColor {
      get { return lineColor;}
      set {
          lineColor = value;
          BackColor = value;
      }
  }
  public Line(){
     Height = 1;//Default thickness
     Width = 100;//Default length
     BackColor = lineColor;
  }
  //for the case you want to draw yourself, add code in this method
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
       base.OnPaint(e);
       //your code
  }
}
//use it
Line line = new Line(){Left = 50, Top = 50};
line.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(line_MouseEnter);
```

If you want to draw the line on your form, I think your line is in fact a structure storing information of a line (thickness, length, start point, end point). So you don't need it to inherit `Control`, and to register `MouseEnter`, you have to add `MouseMove` event handler for your form, not your line. However your line `Rectangle` will help. Again, you still have to calculate your line `Rectangle`, which is not easy as I said before. To demonstrate it, I just calculate the `Rectangle` of your line in a simple way (increase X of both start and end point by 1):

```
//Your control has Size of Empty in this example, it just stores information of your line and is used to register the MouseMove event handler with the Form when its Parent is changed (to Form).
public class Line : Control
{
  public Point start { get; set; }
  public Point end { get; set; }
  public Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
  protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e){
    if(Parent != null){
        Parent.MouseMove -= MouseMoveParent;
        Parent.MouseMove += MouseMoveParent;
    }
  }
  private void MouseMoveParent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
     //the line Rectangle is specified by 4 points
     //I said that this is just for demonstrative purpose because to calculate
     //the exact 4 points (of the line Rectangle), you have to add much more code.
     Point p1 = start;
     Point p2 = new Point(p1.X + 1, p1.Y);
     Point p3 = new Point(end.X + 1, end.Y);
     Point p4 = end;
     System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
     gp.AddPolygon(new Point[]{p1,p2,p3,p4});
     Region lineRegion = new Region(gp);
     if(lineRegion.IsVisible(e.Location)){
         MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
     }
  }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Line line = new Line() { start = new Point(50, 50), end = new Point(100, 100) };
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Controls.Add(line);
  }     
  private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {        
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(line.pen, line.start, line.end);        
  }
}
```

Comment: I overrode the OnPaint method in the Line and created a line using PaintEventArgs utilizing the starting and ending Point in my Line Class. MyEvent Handler was not firing up because i was inherting from control instead of Panel or UserControl. Anyways my problem has been solved. And Thks for the substantial effort in the answer it will be useful for me as a starting point for further features in my Line.

Comment: No, your Control Size has not been initialized and that's why your mouse never entered its region. I've tested with initializing its Size for example (100,50) and the `MouseEnter` is fired. I'm experienced enough to be sure about it. `Panel` or `Control` is not the problem in this case. Inheriting from `Panel` or `UserControl` works because the default Size of `Panel` and `UserControl` is not Empty. If you don't believe, just try adding this line in your Line constructor: `Size = new Size(100,50);` and try moving your mouse over the top-left corner of your form.

Comment: Well i never said you were wrong. Infact you are absolutely right because the event in my code fires up in whenever i enter a rectangular region instead of just firing up on the diagonal line, indicating the presence of a default panel size. Infact right now i am trying to come up with some way to make the event only fire up when the mouse moves over the line instead of the whole panel.